# Почему цвет чёрный, а не белый:

Tags: python, numpy, cv2

Я изучаю cv2 на python. Столкнулся с проблемой - во время создания матрицы с помощи np.ones должен создаться белый фон, но создаётся чёрный. Можно ли это исправить без строки `img1[:] = 1, 1, 1`?

Вот мой код:

```
img1 = np.ones((500, 500, 3), dtype='uint8')
img1[10:150, 200:280] = 105, 201, 105
cv2.imshow('Photo', img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Белый цвет это 255, а 1 - это практически чёрный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы сами говорите программе создать черный фон (вы создаете массив из единиц)

Измените строку

```
img1 = np.ones((500, 500, 3), dtype='uint8')
```

на

```
img1 = np.full((500, 500, 3), 255, dtype='uint8')
```